Pandas Add Unique Values from Groupby to Column
I have a dataframe that lists a users codes
UserID     Code
   123        A
   123        B
   123        A
   456        C
   456        D

How do I add a column that shows all of the users unique codes?
UserID     Code     UniqueCodes
   123        A          [A, B]
   123        B          [A, B]
   123        A          [A, B]
   456        C          [C, D]
   456        D          [C, D]

I tried doing df.groupby(by='UserID')['Code'].agg(['unique']) but that did not work.
I also tried to do df.groupby(by='UserID')['Code'].transform('unique') but I got an error:

'unique' is not a valid function name for transform(name)


You almost did it, the last step was to merge initial dataframe with the grouped-by one:
df.merge(df.groupby(by='UserID')['Code'].agg(['unique']).reset_index(), on = 'UserID')


UserID  Code    unique
0   123 A   [A, B]
1   123 B   [A, B]
2   123 A   [A, B]
3   456 C   [C, D]
4   456 D   [C, D]


Another possible solution, which uses transform that creates a list with the unique codes. This list must be replicated as many times as the length of the group.
df['UniqueCodes'] = df.groupby(
    'UserID')['Code'].transform(lambda x: [x.unique().tolist()] * len(x))

Output:
   UserID Code UniqueCodes
0     123    A      [A, B]
1     123    B      [A, B]
2     123    A      [A, B]
3     456    C      [C, D]
4     456    D      [C, D]


You can use df.groupby and groupby.unique and map on column "UserID":
df['UniqueCodes'] = df['UserID'].map(df.groupby('UserID')['Code'].unique())

Output:
   UserID Code UniqueCodes
0     123    A      [A, B]
1     123    B      [A, B]
2     123    A      [A, B]
3     456    C      [C, D]
4     456    D      [C, D]

